# MonoTouch - how can I pass a value back to my controller from a custom UIActionSheet?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiactionsheet, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView. I have implemented a UITableViewDelegate and overridden the RowSelected event to display a custom ActionSheet with UIPickerView i.e. if the user selects a row the ActionSheet displays a list of choices for that row.

What I'm looking to do is ... when the user dismisses the custom ActionSheet (by pressing a Done button), the ActionSheet is dismissed, and the value of the selected item is passed back to the UIViewController for display purposes.

I'm a little unsure as to the best way to handle this. I was hoping someone might have some pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should subclass `UIActionSheet` and subscribe to `Dismissed` and set a property for the value the user selected.  (You can also do other work like fill up the action sheet from within the subclass)

Your controller can then subscribe to `Dismissed` and read your new property.